# Play audio into a phone call on Android in 2.3+

Tags: android

Is it possible to play audio into a phone call on Android in 2.3+? For instance, I'd like to play an MP3 **into** a call that was placed from the device (not record the audio).

I've seen people ask about earlier versions of Android and the responses are generally along the lines of "when the hardware supports it, the software will".

So, do the newer Android devices/SDKs support this sort of audio routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, sorry. As far as I know the only way to do that is to output the audio via speaker so it would be caught by microphone.